# C# Iterate through string with Linq .Select()

Tags: c#

Why can't I iterate through a string and add the letters (chars) to a HashSet like in the example above.

I tried to execute this part of the code but the HashSet was empty.
`

```
HashSet<char> chars2 = new HashSet<char>();
myString.Select(l => chars2.Add(l));
```

`

Answer (score 1):

Delayed/deferred execution! There is no need to evaluate the `Select`

If you add a `ToList()` to the end, it will execute your lambda and will add the items.

You can also change it to a `ForEach`

Knowing this, beware that if you do not a `ToList()` to it, and iterate your collection, it will execute it again and again, so if your Select is expensive to run, make sure to run it once.

Comment: or just `new HashSet<char>(myString)`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the "example above" is, but you're using LINQ incorrectly. The `Select` method should not be used to create side effects. `chars2.Add()` creates a side effect.

In addition, most Linq methods are not executed if they don't need to be. This is called "Deferred Execution".

Instead, use a foreach, which is intended to create side effects while looping through elements.

```
var myString = "abcd";
HashSet<char> chars2 = new HashSet<char>();

foreach (var chr in myString)
{
    chars2.Add(chr);
}
```

There are also more direct ways to create a hash set from specifically a string

```
myString.ToHashSet()
new HashSet<char>(myString)
```

Answer (score 1):

`Select` is a LINQ method. Most LINQ methods are intermediate expressions and don't consume the collection. You must call a terminal operation such as `ToList` or `ForEach` to actually "execute" the query.

But note that using Select/ForEach to add to a set is a bit odd: you are using a functional approach to execute a side-effect (inherently non-functional!).

Instead, use the extension method [`ToHashSet()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tohashset?view=netframework-4.7.2) directly if available in your .NET version:

```
HashSet<char> chars2 = myString.ToHashSet();
```

Comment: Can’t see `ToHashSet` in the [string methods doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=net-7.0)? Is it an extension method?

Comment: @stuartd yes, it's an extension method similar to `ToList`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tohashset?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Should have just tried it myself really, sorry. That’s what happens when you open SO on your phone..